# Android Visualizer waveform for Voice recording through MediaRecorder

Tags: android, media-player, mediarecorder, waveform, visualizer

I'm writing a simple Voice Recording app in Android and want to display a waveform based on the voice input. I have gone through the Visualizer class and got it to work with the playback of the voice recording (through MediaPlayer)

```
        mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with the MediaRecorder class. Is there a way to use the Visualizer class for MediaRecorder or is it meant only for MediaPlayer?
Ideally I want similar wave forms for both recording & playback.

Comment: I have used getNoiseLevel() to get the Noise level and showing the level in VisualizerView class

Comment: cool. you could answer your own question, that would clarify this topic a lot :)

Comment: @Harish you mean [getMaxAmplitude](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude())? I can't find anything call getNoiseLevel().

Comment: Sorry, I meant getMaxAmplitude() and then normalize the value for the waveform